# JavaScript RegExp Differences

Tags: javascript, regex

What is the difference between

```
var regEx = /\d/;
```

and

```
var regEx = new RegEx("\d");
```

Bob

Answer (score 8):

Both evaluate to be the same exact regex, but the first is a literal, meaning you cannot use any variables inside it, you cannot dynamically generate a regex.

The second uses the constructor explicitly and can be used to create dynamic regular expressions.

```
var x = '3', r = ( new RegExp( x + '\d' ) ); r.test('3d')
```

The above is an example of dynamically constructing the regex with the constructor, which you can not do in literal form.

In 99% of cases you will just rely on the first version ( literal ) for all your regexpes in JS. In an advanced scenario where you need say, user input to dynamically construct a regex then that's when you'll need the second form.

**EDIT #1**: **The first matches a digit, the second just matches the letter `d`. You have to double-escape the second one in order for it to equal the first one, which I assume you meant to do. Just remember the advice I typed above is accurate if the second example is `new RegExp('\\d')`.**

```
/\d/.test('3') // true
( new RegExp('\d') ).test('3') // false
( new RegExp('\\d') ).test('3') // true
```

Comment: Thanks for the explaination, the reason I asked was I had this expression /^ +|[\\/#;]| +$/gi (1 or more spaces OR contains \ / # ; OR ends with one or more space). When using the non-constructor every odd time the result resulted in false. Eg. the result was alternating. When using the constructor everything worked as expected every time. Strange!

Comment: There is yet another difference: The literal only creates *one* object at *parse time* whereas the constructor function always creates a new object. This will be changed though in ES5 and the literal will also always return a new object.